# How to apply daily changing rate on all products in ASP.Net Desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net, pos

I have a POS Software in ASP.NET Desktop App. I want to apply daily rate on the prices of Gold products. Is there anyone who can guide me well?

Comment: could you elaborate your question?

Comment: I want to enter the Gold rate that will be applied to all Gold products and I can get new prices. So how can i code it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.